# Unselected object is rendering in preview although eye is disabled - blender 2.79

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

Although my plane is hidden, (eye disabled in outliner), it does render in the preview render when it shouldn't be happening.

I could create a new file and append the objects if it's merely a glitch, but my scene is way too big. I haven't been able to solve this issue on my own.

I attached my blend file.
Thank you for your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please upload your demo file on [Blend-Exchange](https://blend-exchange.com/) and [edit] your post to include the download link.

Comment: You could add some images to let us know how you are setting up your blend scene. And more info, the more, the better

Comment: Please do share, as suggested, otherwise we don't have enough to go on.

Comment: I added more info as suggested

Comment: From your image, it looks like you have "Preview active render layer in viewport" On, and because of that, it's giving you a preview of your final render. The option is below your viewport to the right, very close to the corner, after the pause simbol/ button ( the double "II") Turn it off and see

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something broke in your file  When I open it, it doesn't even display anything in the render settings:

[image]

It keeps showing hidden objects, even new one I make myself.

A way to fix it is to make a new clean scene > select all with <kbd>A</kbd> > <kbd>X</kbd> > Delete.
Then File > Append (or <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>F1</kbd>), navigate to your file, go inside its Objects folder, <kbd>A</kbd> to select all, and <kbd>⏎ Enter</kbd> to confirm.

This way you have a new clean functional file:

[image]